# How to create a "Discount Plugin"

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, virtuemart

VirtueMart doesn't have a lot of plugins... So, I thought about creating a plugin which shows the percent of the price of the product in ofert.

Just making a div with ::after (CSS3) and inserting it in the product detail view of the specific category (body with a class).

Now... if you want a category with many products, and each one with diferents discounts, we need to write the product's price's percent variable in the content of the ::after.

The question is how? Where can I find those variables? Where's those files?
I'm using a VERTEX Template (Shape5).

I have read that it's in /your_template/html/com_virtuemart/.. but it's nothing there...

So... Can anyone help me? Or tell me about a plugin which shows the product's percent discount in a "beautiful" way..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make discounts in VM2 with: 
VM2 -> Taxes & Calculation rules -> and make a new rule with: 
-Price modifier after tax;
-Math Operation=(-);
-Value=(Your Discount)

You can even set dates or choose categories or whatnot.
Maybe it's not a elegant solution for your non-tech end users/admins, but in the administration they get a dropdown of discounts under tax rules which does the job, the styling can be done too. You can have a look from where this is done, i believe the files are under: 
/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/calc/